# Drag and dropping a button (Button won't follow)

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm having a bit of trouble making drag and drop a button in a panel and panel to recognize it and display Message with buttons name

So far I managed the part of dragging and dropping and recognizing however I'm missing the visual style of dragging, when I press with mouse it will just sit on the same place, it won't follow cursor. How do I make it follow the mouse?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panel1.AllowDrop = true;
        panel1.DragEnter += panel_DragEnter;
        panel1.DragDrop += panel_DragDrop;
        button1.MouseDown += button1_MouseDown;
    }

    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.DoDragDrop(button1.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
        button1.Location= new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    private void panel_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void panel_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString());

    }
```

Comment: have the location of the button follow the mouse movements

Comment: @Plutonix could you write a code example, I know I have to make that work but still no luck with making it happen

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to keep in mind that the `DoDragDrop` method doesn't return the Position you dropped the object. The `DragDrop` event handles that.

To move the control while you're dragging you use the [`DragOver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragover(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the panel. In the implementation you need to compensate for the fact that the X and Y coordinates in the EventArgs are Screen based while you need Clientbased coordinates to correctly position the control. The [`PointToClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx) is instrumental in that:

```
private void panel_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Button).FullName))
    {
        var draggedButton = (Button)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Button).FullName);

        var screenpos = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        var clientPos =  panel1.PointToClient(screenpos);
        // calc offset
        draggedButton.Location = new Point(
            clientPos.X + panel1.Left,
            clientPos.Y + panel1.Top);
    }
}
```

Notice that your Data now contains the actual Button, instead of only the text. This makes that you can dragdrop multiple buttons, not only button1.

Your `DragDrop` event should now look like this:

```
private void panel_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Button).FullName))
    {
        var draggedButton = (Button)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Button).FullName);
        MessageBox.Show(draggedButton.Text);

        var screenpos = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        var clientPos = panel1.PointToClient(screenpos);
        draggedButton.Location = new Point(
            clientPos.X + panel1.Left,
            clientPos.Y + panel1.Top);
    }
}
```

And `DragEnter` only slightly changed so it could handle the Button control instead of the text:

```
private void panel_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Button).FullName)) // button
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

And finally to get it all started and wired up the constructor code and the `MouseDown` implementation of the button:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    panel1.AllowDrop = true;
    panel1.DragEnter += panel_DragEnter;
    panel1.DragDrop += panel_DragDrop;
    panel1.DragOver += panel_DragOver;
    button1.MouseDown += button1_MouseDown;

}

private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    button1.DoDragDrop(button1, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```